# When using node.js and socket.io, why can't I just open the client.html file instead of typing localhost in the address bar?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am just curious. I think it has something to do with that socket.io temporary file, but I don't really get it...

Comment: A local file with an local url has no notion of "server". You violate the cross origin restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers generally don't allow HTTP requests to be made to domains different than the one the page is on.  So a client.html file that's opened as a "file://..." URL in the browser can only talk to other "file://..." urls. (i.e static pages only).  However socket.io requires a real webserver on the backend, so it has to be "http://..."

There are also other considerations, around how file:// urls are treated differently. (e.g. you can't set cookies, XHR requests to file:// urls don't have HTTP status codes, etc.)